# Prove that $S^{3}$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Prove that $S^{3}$  is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I think this is an overall result. More generally,  $S^{n}$  is not differeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

For example, I have already proved that there is no immersion between $S$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Does this help to prove?

Comment: $S^3$ is compact.

Comment: A diffeomorphism is in particular an immersion. If there is no immersion, there is no diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

A compact space and a non-compact space cannot be homeomorphic. In particular, they cannot be diffeomorphic.

Comment: How to prove fact?

Comment: Which fact? That a compact space and a non-compact space cannot be homeomorphic? Or that if two differentiable manifolds are not homeomorphic then they are not diffeomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Take any topological invariant and see what happens. Compactness for instance.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more elementary approach: any continuous map $S^3\to\mathbb R^3$ must be bounded, since $S^3$ is compact. So it can't be surjective. In particular, differentiable maps can't be surjective, so there is no diffeomorphism between the two.

Answer (score 1):

More advanced, or sledgehammer, or algebraic topology approach:  they have different homologies (or homotopy groups).  That is, for instance,  $\pi_n(S^n)\cong\Bbb Z$, but $\pi_n(\Bbb R^n)\cong0$.

So, in fact there is not even a homeomorphism, much less a diffeomorphism.

Comment: i.e. not even a (weak) homotopy equivalence...